# How many client can a multi-threaded server handle?

Tags: c#

I am using multithreaded server to handle client communication, I don't know how many clients can this server handle. If number of clients increase will it be able to handle them? I am using it on core2duo processor.
Will starting server on different port solve the problem, if i redirect half of the clients to new server with another port?

Here is my code for server

```
Public void ListenForClients()
        {
            this.tcpListener.Start();

            while (true)
            {      
                try
                {
                    TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                    NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();   //create networkstream for connected client                         
                    Console.WriteLine(((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());//client ipaddress
                    Console.WriteLine("connecting..");
                    Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(updatedb));                    
                    clientThread.Start(client);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("exception" + ex.ToString());
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the server process actually doing?

Comment: This is perhaps a question for ServerFault ... http://serverfault.com/questions/350458/how-do-you-do-load-testing-and-capacity-planning-for-databases

Comment: Server receive RSSI values from clients then send back to client after filtering RSSI.

Comment: Not many, hundreds at most.  Threads scale very poorly, the require a *lot* of resources.  You make it scale by using I/O completion ports, supported in .net with the BeginAcceptSocket and BeginReceive methods.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx) and similar posts by the author. He explains there in great detail how multi threading is used by IIS / ASP.NET.

What you must remember, is that even if You can create more threads (by running anothre instance of your application, as you suggested, for example), it doesnt mean your application will be more responsive / return the expected answers to the clients faster, as there can be only as much running threads at any given moment as the number of CPUS your server has.

I dont think you need to write your code in an expectation of collapsing, but to work in a direction of more of an async processing, as the ISS server (which is practically doing the same - servicing TCP connections) is doing. Theres no reason not to use the thread pool provided by .NET, let it handle the real number of co-existing threads at every given moment, and let the other requests queue untill a thread becomes availibale.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually trying it, everything else is a guess.  As Hans Passant says, your strategy of creating a new thread for every request will not scale well.  It may seem ok at first, but you should see performance fall off badly over a few hundred simultaneous users.  In addition, it looks like the work will be communicating with a database (updatedb), so these threads you've created will just be sending data to an external process and waiting for a reply?  That's the worst use of a thread.  See if you can use [asynchronous sql updates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664464%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx).